# Angular Binding In Template Not Resolving

Tags: html, angularjs

I have the following directive...

```
app.directive('layoutPreview', function () {
return {
    restrict : 'E',
    transclude : false,
    scope: {
        layout: '@',
        previewid : '='
    },
    controller : function($scope){
        console.log($scope.layout);
        console.log($scope.previewid);
        layoutPreview($scope.layout, "canvas-layout-" + $scope.previewid);
    },
    template:
    '<canvas height="200" width="350" id="canvas-layout-{{previewid}}">' + 
    '</canvas>'
}
})
```

Which, once placed renders a canvas with a preview. However, {{previewid}} inside the template never resolves and I'm unsure why. Both of the log outputs show the correct values too. Even an output in my layoutPreview() function shows the correct id of the element it should be searching for. 
Inspecting the page shows that the angular binding hasn't resolved.
Any ideas?

Comment: Please add the rest of the code ([a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: What if you use a function? Like `'<canvas height="200" width="350" id="canvas-layout-{{getPreviewid()}}"></canvas>` and `$scope.getPreviewid = function() { console.log('call') }`? Is it getting logged?

Comment: @JeffreyRoosendaal No, there is nothing in the logs from that.

Comment: Works fine for me. Do you have any console errors? Please show how you are using this directive, or create a live example.

Comment: @FrankModica As explain in an answer below, the value is correct and logs correctly when output from inside the controller on the directive. However when output from the template, it shows undefined.

Comment: @BenBrookes I understand but I am able to see the correct ID in the template, so I think something else is going on. We could help you better if you create a live example which reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* it's because the template gets rendered before the controller is created, and therefore the bindings do not work; ie `$scope` does not exist at the time of rendering.

Try:

```
template: function($attrs) {
    return '<canvas height="200" width="350" id="canvas-layout-'
        + $attrs.previewid
        + '"></canvas>';
}
```

Also, if `previewid` is just a string, use:

```
scope: {
    previewid : '@'
},
```

`=` is for *two-way binding* and objects.

---

This will insert the previewid *before* rendering the template.

---

*Sidenote: You don't have to include `transclude: false` if it's `false`, and I would recommend using `component` instead of `directive` if you use Angular 1.5+.*

Comment: Thank you for your help but it didn't seem to make a difference. I have logged the previewid in the first line of the directive controller and it is as it should be. However, inspecting the canvas elements still shows that their ID is undefined, even using your proposed method.

Comment: Hm, this should work.. What if you put `console.log($attrs.previewid)` before the `return` statement in the snippet above? What does it log?

Comment: It logs undefined. However when logged from the controller it shows the correct value.

Comment: Try `previewid : '@'`